# Script editor: How to get Product name from line_item

Tags: shopify

While working on a "Line Items" script, I want to display product name as part of a UI message. I can get the variant name using `line_item.variant.title` and product object using 'line_item.variant.product` but how do I get the product title?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to the title of the product by default, you can refer the docs here: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor/shopify-scripts#product

But what you can do is pass a custom property to the product when you are adding it to the cart with the product title and refer to that property in the Shopify Scripts code.

`<input name="properties[__product-title]" value="{{ product.title }}" />`

And in the script:

```
Input.cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
  next if line_item.properties.empty?
  productTitle = line_item.properties['__product-title']
  // Rest of the logic
end
```

Comment: Great. Worth a try

Answer (score 1):

You can access title's from the variant by using

https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor/shopify-scripts#variant

`line_item.variant.title`